# Progressive Web App "Manifest does not contain a suitable icon"

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I am building a dynamic progressive web app. Due to this the Icons have to be able to change. For this I have a public S3 bucket that I am pointing to in the manifest.json file.

Here is what that looks like:

```
{
"name": "Tenant 3",
"short_name": "Tenant 3",
"description": "Tenant 3",
"manifest_version": "0.11",
"icons": [{
        "src": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucket/smallIcon",
        "sizes": "192x192"
    }, {
        "src": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucket/largeIcon",
        "sizes": "512x512"
    }
],
"display": "standalone",
"start_url": "http://localhost:60003/",
"scope": "http://localhost:60003/"
}
```

However, when it loads I get the error:

`Manifest does not contain a suitable icon - PNG format of at least 144px is required, the sizes attribute must be set, and the purpose attribute, if set, must include "any"`

Both of my icons are PNG and are the exact sizes I have set in the manifest when I go to my S3 URL and download the images the are PNG and the correct dimensions. Also it looks like they are loading fine, here is a screenshot of the DevTools window.

[image]

Is there an issue with using a URL as the src and not a file directly? If so are they any alternatives to point to a image that is not in my code directory and hosted remotely?

Comment: Adding "type" : "image/png" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

This is a relatively old question. In a few words, your `manifest.js` file does not have a declaration for the default icon size of `144x144` in PNG, SVG, or WebP format. Also, remember the new `purpose` attribute.

The current warning message would be:

> "Not supplied icon is at least 144px square in PNG, SVG or WebP format.".

Therefore you might want to have the following declaration for a PNG example:

```
{
    "src": "/relative-path-to-icon-file-with-dimensions-144x144.png",
    "sizes": "144x144",
    "type": "image/png",
    "purpose": "any"
}
```

for SVG or WebP change the type to "image/svg" or "image/webp"

Answer (score 0):

Icon must be place in public directory.
And give that path in package.json for generating assets.